# OC4J EAR file format - support jar files

Tags: jakarta-ee, oc4j, ear

I've worked with JBoss and WebLogic before, but this is the first job I've been at where we've used OC4J. We're using version 10.1.2.0.2, but using JRE 1.4.2. I'm creating an EAR file, complete with one WAR file and one EJB file. Instead of entity beans, we're using Spring/Hibernate to access the db, so the EJBs are session beans.
The question is where to put the Spring and Hibernate jar files. I've tried putting them in the ejb-jar file under META-INF/lib as well as the lib directory of the EAR file, but to no avail. I think that's because we're not running JRE 5.
The closest online help I've seen is [this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14017/deploy.htm#sthref441).

Where do they go?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I needed the orion-application.xml file, which is put in the ear/META-INF directory. I put all my support jar files in the ear/lib directory.

```
<orion-application>
  <library path="lib"/>
</orion-application>
```